# Auto-renewable Subscriptions and sharing customer email addresses

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, in-app-purchase, subscription

I did went through the documentation but didn't find how Apple will share user info such as email if the user elects to provide his email address. The Subscription Receipt doesn't provide any info about the user also in Apple documentation they mentioned:

> Customers purchasing a subscription through the App Store will be given the option of providing the publisher with their name, email address, and zip code.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is buried in the iTunes Connect guide.

> The customer’s opted-in information will be made available in the Sales and Trends module of iTunes Connect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So in the sales and trends in iTunes Connect will have a list of all users emails where we can export them as excel sheet or other type of files?

Comment: Is there any option to disable collecting information from users?

Comment: @AnilSivadas At this time you can't disable the display of the opt-in window. Marco Arment speaks of this unfortunate fact in his blog: http://www.marco.org/2012/01/06/autorenewable-subscription-restrictions